Error when trying to run a statement using a cursor
Under Oracle 19c I made a simple select with cursors :
select
 'file1' as "filename",
 cursor(
   select
     a.NOM "nom",
     :P17_DATE_CALCULEE as "date_devis",
     a.PRENOM as "prenom",
     a.ADRESSE as "adresse",
     a.CODE_POSTAL as "code_postal",
     a.VILLE as "ville",
     a.TELEPHONE as "telephone",
     :P17_TOTAL as "total",
     a.ID as "numero_devis",
     cursor ( select
              b.motif as "motif",
              b.DESTINATION as "destination",
              b.DISTANCE as "distance",
              b.PRIX as "prix"
              from DY_DEVIS_LIGNE b
              where B.ID_DEVIS = :P17_NUMERO) 
   from DY_DEVIS a
   where a.ID = :P17_NUMERO
 ) as "data"
from dual

I get an error ORA-00932 inconsistent datatype :
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CURSOR
What is wrong with the cursor ?

Please have a look at (and read): Examples Using Cursors, because you are using cursor in an incorrect way.

@Luuk, that syntax is correct for a "cursor expression", check the docs

Tagged oracle-apex , since you have bind variables that suggest this is sql source for a an apex page component. Where exactly are you executing this query - is it the source for a report ? What result are you expecting ? Please provide as much information as possible.

@KoenLostrie: But DBFIDDLE does not seem to like it.  (you might need to remove the --  before the SELECT...)

@Luuk - db<>fiddle doesn't know how to handle the nested cursor; it struggles with some other less-common data types too, not unreasonably. The syntax of the query is valid though, and you can use it within a PL/SQL block in a fiddle to show it's valid.

So the issue is how Apex is executing the query and trying to retrieve the results; from the error it seems to be assuming the second column value of the main query (or the 10th of the first cursor subquery) is a string, not a ref cursor. No idea though if that's a problem in other code that hasn't been included, or if it's just something Apex can't handle.
